# How to test ArrayField Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

Django 1.11
I am testing the `forms` which is `Meta` by `ArrayList` in the `Model`.
I have cut out the unrelated code from my question.

`models.py`

```
class MailAPIScheduler(DirtyFieldsMixin, AbstractSoftModelController):
    summary_email_receivers = ArrayField(
        models.EmailField(blank=True),
        blank=True
    )
```

`forms.py`

```
import json

from django import forms

from eneos.apps.mail_api_schedule.models import MailAPIScheduler


class MailAPISchedulerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    schedule_time = forms.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = MailAPIScheduler
        fields = [
            'api_url',
            'schedule_time',
            'parameters',
            'summary_email_receivers',
        ]

    def clean_schedule_time(self):
        dt = self.cleaned_data['schedule_time']
        return {
            'hour': dt.hour,
            'minute': dt.minute,
        }
```

`tests.py`

```
def test_mail_api_scheulder_form(self):
    data = {
        'api_url': 'http://hotmail.com',
        'schedule_time': '9:30',
        'parameters': json.dumps({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}),
        'summary_email_receivers': ["elcolie@gmail.com", "sarit.r@codium.co"]
    }
    form = MailAPISchedulerForm(data)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    self.assertEqual(True, form.is_valid())
    self.assertDictEqual(form.cleaned_data.get('schedule_time'), {
        'hour': 9,
        'minute': 30,
    })
```

`Run tests`

```
$ python manage.py test eneos.apps.mail_api_schedule.tests.TestMailAPIScheduler.test_mail_api_scheulder_form --nomigrations --settings=eneos.config.settings.local
Hey, I'm Local!
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
> /Users/el/Code/eneos-pos-web/eneos/apps/mail_api_schedule/tests.py(188)test_mail_api_scheulder_form()
-> self.assertEqual(True, form.is_valid())
(Pdb) n
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please add the full traceback. The pdb output is not helpful to us, since we can't interact with it. You could use `w` in the debugger to get a stack trace.

Comment: You could try to replace this with a string. `'summary_email_receivers': ["elcolie@gmail.com", "sarit.r@codium.co"]` -> `'elcolie@gmail.com sarit.r@codium.co'`. Http form data are sent as strings, not python lists.

Comment: You are right `'summary_email_receivers': "elcolie@gmail.com, sarit.r@codium.co",` Use comma seperate them. Thank you very much.

Comment: In order to avoid these kind of errors, I like to perform more granular tests. In your example, at first test 'self.assertTrue(isinstance(your_dict, dict))', then check if every key is in the dict 'self.assertIn('api_url', your_dict)', and finally test the var contents, 'self.assertEquals(your_dict['api_url'], ...)'.

Comment: @Dos Thank you for your suggestion. I will follow it.